# Actualizar panel despues de descargar file

Tags: primefaces

Hola estoy haciendo una carga y descarga de un txt. Cuando le de clic en " Descargar" el txt, este se descarga,  y setteo algunas variables, posteriormente se debe renderizar otro panel, mi problema es que  descargo el archivo y el panel no se  renderiza, si vuelvo a dar clic en descargar, entonces se renderiza el panel.  Espero darme a entender .

Panel con botones :

```
<p:panel styleClass="panelGridConsulta">
    <div class="panelGrid botonesFlujoCaptcha">
        <p:commandButton styleClass="estilo" value="Terminar"
                         actionListener="#{bean.reset}" ajax="false"/>

        <p:commandButton id="comdDwn" value="Descargar archivo"
                         actionListener="#{fileBean.resetValida}" ajax="false"
                         disabled="#{fileBean.status ==null or bean.statusBtnDescargarArchivo ==null}"
                         update="panelDwn" styleClass="estilo">
            <p:fileDownload value="#{fileBean.file}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </div>
</p:panel>
```

Metodo en MB:

```
public void resetValida() {
    setStatus(null);
    setStatusDownload("Favor de seleccionar y validar un archivo.");
    terminarMasiva = "activo descarga";
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("terminaDescargaArch");

}
```

Panel que se debe renderizar una vez se  descargue el txt:

```
<p:panel id="terminaDescargaArch" styleClass="panelGridConsulta"
rendered="#{uploadFileBean.terminarMasiva != null}">
    <h:outputLabel styleClass="txtLabel izq3"
                   value="Test render after download:"/>
</p:panel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encierra en panel a renderizar en otro panel,  colocale un id y renderiza este panel, en lugar del interno.

```
<p:panel id="terminaDescargaArch" styleClass="panelGridConsulta">
    <p:panel rendered="#{fileUploadBean.terminaMasiva =! null}">
        ...
    </p:panel>
</p:panel>
```

En tu commandButton:

```
<p:commandButton .... update="terminaDescargaArch" />
```